# Add string to array based on flag

Tags: c#

Is there any way to improve this kind of code? I have converted this from production code for privacy reasons, so there might be some mistakes.

```
public class AddNewUserDto
{

    public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }
    public bool IsRead { get; set; }
    public bool IsWrite { get; set; }


    public string[] GetRolesByDto()
    {
        List<string> roles = new List<string>();

        if (this.IsAdmin)
        {
            roles.Add(USER_ROLES.ADMIN);
        }
        if (this.IsRead)
        {
            roles.Add(USER_ROLES.IsRead);
        }
        if (this.IsWrite)
        {
            roles.Add(USER_ROLES.IsWrite);
        }
        if (this.IsEntityUser)
        {
            roles.Add(USER_ROLES.IsEntityUser);
        }

        return roles.ToArray();
    }
}

public static class USER_ROLES
{
    public const string IsAdmin= "Admin";
    public const string IsRead= "Read";
    public const string IsWrite= "Write";
    public const string IsEntityUser = "EntityUser";
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`string`s are probably the wrong choice to represent roles. You lose the power of the type system -- the compiler won't pick up on typos, e.g. "Amdin". Consider using an `enum` instead.

Be consistent with your naming. Why is it `USER_ROLES.IsRead` and `USER_ROLES.Write` (not `IsWrite`)? Stick to the standard naming conventions, e.g. write `UserRole.IsRead` instead of `USER_ROLES.IsRead`.

Does the calling code really need an array returned? It would probably be fine with an `IEnumerable`.

If we change the return type to `IEnumerable<UserRole>`, we can write

```
public IEnumerable<UserRole> GetRoles()
{
    if (this.IsAdmin)
    {
        yield return UserRole.Admin;
    }

    if (this.IsRead)
    {
        yield return UserRole.Read;
    }

    if (this.IsWrite)
    {
        yield return UserRole.Write;
    }

    if (this.IsEntityUser)
    {
        yield return UserRole.EntityUser;
    }
}
```

But I'm guessing you're asking more about the repetition. Here's one way to get around it -- create an association between the booleans and the values. Here I've used a dictionary; it's possibly a bit of overkill but it does give us the nice initialiser syntax:

```
public IEnumerable<UserRole> GetRoles()
{
    var roles = new Dictionary<UserRole, bool>
    {
        { UserRole.Admin, this.IsAdmin },
        { UserRole.Read, this.IsRead },
        { UserRole.Write, this.IsWrite },
        { UserRole.EntityUser, this.IsEntityUser }
    };
    return roles.Where(role => role.Value)
                .Select(role => role.Key);
}
```

Other options would be an array of `KeyValuePair`s, an array of `Tuple`s, etc.

Comment: Actually i modified the code a bit so that i don't leak the company code to online community, thank for the dictionary techniquies :D

Answer (score 7):

This is similar advice to what you've already received, but I'd like to expand on why it would be better to return an `IEnumerable`.

First off, it's always better to code to abstractions rather than implementations. `Array` is an implementation of `IEnumerable`.

> ```
> [SerializableAttribute]
> [ComVisibleAttribute(true)]
> public abstract class Array : ICloneable, 
>     IList, ICollection, IEnumerable, IStructuralComparable, IStructuralEquatable
> ```

[MSDN Array class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx)

By returning an `IEnemerable` your code becomes less brittle. It becomes easier to change the code to return a `List` without breaking the client code.

And returning a list makes a lot of sense here. This is the very first line of code that you have.

> ```
> List<string> roles = new List<string>();
> ```

And then you "cast" it to an `Array` when you return it.

> ```
> return roles.ToArray();
> ```

Returning an `IEnumerable` lets you simply return the `List`.

---

Side note:

Using `var` to declare the `roles` variable also makes sense. It reduces repetition and will make it so there's one less change to make if you decide to change the implementation.

```
var roles = new List<string>();
```

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on the answer by @mjolka:

You could also use a **[[Flags]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447/what-does-the-flags-enum-attribute-mean-in-c)** enum.

```
[Flags]
public enum Role {
    Admin,
    Read,
    Write,
}
```

---

```
something.Role = Role.Read | Role.Write;
// ...
if(something.Role.HasFlag(Role.Read)) {
    // ...
}
```